# Change Enumerate Items to Khmer Unicode Alphabet

Tags: fonts, lists, enumerate, unicode

Here is my code that change default enumerate item to `roman number`

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\theenumi{\roman{enumi}}
\def\theenumii{\roman{enumii}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item one
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item one
            \item two
        \end{enumerate}
        \item two
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item one
            \item two
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

My purpose is to change the second level `\enumii` to `khmer unicode alphabet`.
Is there any way to do that? Or is there any way to map the `latin alphabet` to `khmer alphabet`, i.e.

> a->ក
>
> b->ខ
>
> c->គ

for example?

And here is the link to [download](http://khmer.hawaii.edu/Fonts.html) `Khmer fonts`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @dustin I actually, want the second level item of the enumerate to be 'Khmer (unicode) alphabets'.

Comment: I don't think there is a simple way to do this, but it wouldn't be too hard to construct a `gloss-khmer.ldf` file for `polyglossia` modeled after the `gloss-thai.ldf` file.  You could copy that more or less exactly and use it. Since the work involves actual knowledge of the script and the language, this is not something that the average person here can do.

Comment: @AlanMunn It works fine with document classes `article` and `book` but in `beamer` class, the total page number is still in **arabic**. How can I change it? Note I use the default theme **Madrid**.

Comment: @OLSAY I think you should ask this as a new question, with a minimal `beamer` example.

Comment: @AlanMunn finally, I found it. The last frame number is stored in `\inserttotalframenumber` and its definition was given in **beamerbasemisc.sty** at lines **42** and **166**. Now, I am able to change it :) Thank you anyway!

Comment: @OLSAY  I'm glad you figured it out.  You should post an answer to your new question (and then accept it in a couple of days.)  Also, do you have two accounts (one OL SAY and the other SAY OL)?  If so you can ask one of the moderators to merge them for you.  Just go into the chat when one of them is there.

Comment: @AlanMunn OK, I will answer it anyway. For my former account **SAY OL**, I think I forgot the password and so use this new account.

Answer (score 14):

The `\alph` command that uses the latin alphabet is just a simple list:

```
\def\@alph#1{%
  \ifcase#1\or a\or b\or c\or d\or e\or f\or g\or h\or i\or j\or
   k\or l\or m\or n\or o\or p\or q\or r\or s\or t\or u\or v\or w\or x\or
    y\or z\else\@ctrerr\fi}
```

So once you have Khmer fonts set up, and know the alphabet it should be simple to add a similar command.

[image]

I used xetex and an existing font (DaunPenh) on my Windows system that covers this Unicode range and made a `\khmercount` command that (I hope, if I got that right) covers the first few slots in the alphabet.

If you are using pdflatex you will need to change the `^^^^` Unicode notation to whatever syntax your font package needs. I didn't go any further than the first few as I don't know if the counting order you need matches the Unicode order. Sorry I can not read this script at all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\theenumi{\roman{enumi}}
\def\theenumii{\khmercount{enumii}}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DaunPenh}

\makeatletter
\def\khmercount#1{\expandafter\@khmercount\csname c@#1\endcsname}

% extend as needed!
\def\@khmercount#1{%
  \ifcase#1\or
   ^^^^1780\or
   ^^^^1781\or
   ^^^^1782\or
   ^^^^1783\or
   ^^^^1784\or
   ^^^^1785\or
   ^^^^1786\else
   \@ctrerr\fi}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item one
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item one
            \item two
        \end{enumerate}
        \item two
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item one
            \item two
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works fine. Anyway, how can I know and understand all of your syntax (I mean keyword like c@ or @ctrerr ....)? Because I downloaded manual from CTAN and other websites but they have no such special syntax. Especially, when I open the default class or package, I see some other special syntax that I rarely see in the user guide. So where can I find, if possible download, the book that show all of the syntax for writing package or class?

Comment: @SayOL That is just copied from the source of latex, you can get a documented version of that as source2e.tex (`textdoc source2e`)

Comment: I found source2e.pdf instead from CTAN. Here is the link http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf And is it the source codes you meant?

Comment: @SayOL yes although I tend to just use `latex2e.ltx` (which will be in tex/macros/latex/base in your distribution, which is the same without the comments