# Khmer Unicode Enumeration

Tags: enumerate, unicode

I saw two posts related to my question. And I tried to merge the two but my limited understanding of Latex does not allow me to do so...

I want to use first level enumeration like 1. 2. 3. , which means I do not have change anything. However, for the second-level enumeration, I would like to put it as Khmer Unicode alphabet with a dot after it ក. ខ. គ.

Khmer Unicode Enumerate:
[Change Enumerate Items to Khmer Unicode Alphabet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128694/change-enumerate-items-to-khmer-unicode-alphabet)

How to change to [] from ():
[Enumerated list with square brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42905/enumerated-list-with-square-brackets)

And this is what I want. [image: Khmer Enumerate]

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: @SayOL I just use \item[ក] there. If I change all environment to Khmer, it is  file but 1 becomes ១ etc. I just wanna use 1 and ក for some special occasions.

Comment: We do not need to map `Latin alphabets` to `Khmer alphabets` anymore. We just use `polyglossia` package. I have already done it.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily{\khmerfont}{Khmer OS}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=arabic]{khmer}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\let\@alph\@khmeralph
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=(\alph*)}
\makeatother
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[start=3]
        \item 
        \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item ធាតុនីមួយៗ
            \item ធាតុនីមួយៗ
            \item ធាតុនីមួយៗ
            \item ធាតុនីមួយៗ
        \end{enumerate}
        \end{multicols}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variant which does not change the main font, derived from [Change Enumerate Items to Khmer Unicode Alphabet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128694/change-enumerate-items-to-khmer-unicode-alphabet). It changes to Khmer labeling only locally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\makeatletter
\def\khmercount#1{\expandafter\@khmercount\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@khmercount#1{{% extend as needed!
  \fontspec{Khmer OS}%
  \ifcase#1\or
   ^^^^1780\or
   ^^^^1781\or
   ^^^^1782\or
   ^^^^1783\or
   ^^^^1784\or
   ^^^^1785\or
   ^^^^1786\else
   \@ctrerr\fi}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item
    \begin{multicols}{2}
      {%
      \def\theenumii{\khmercount{enumii}}
      \def\labelenumii{[\theenumii]}
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item \label{one} one
        \item two
        \item three
        \item four
      \end{enumerate}%
      }%
    \end{multicols}
  \item
    \begin{multicols}{2}
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item one
        \item two
        \item three
        \item four
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
  \end{enumerate}
  See item~\ref{one}.
\end{document}
```

[image]