# How to use locale numbering / custom numbering for Burmese?

Tags: page-numbering, languages, locale

I'm trying to use Burmese numbers (၁၂၃၄၅၆၇၈၉) in my document, but I'm having a rough time of it. I found a possible solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17878/how-do-i-use-locale-numbering-for-page-numbers-footers-etc), though it's quite a bit of work, and I'm not sure if there isn't a simpler solution to the problem.

The reason I want Burmese numbering is that the font I'm using (Noto Serif Myanmar) won't render non-Burmese characters, including Arabic numerals and Latin script, instead giving me an empty box. Not sure if that is a problem here or with the font itself. I switched to this font from Padauk because it looks much nicer, but if needed I will switch back to Padauk for the Latin script and Arabic numeral support.

Comment: Most of the solutions mentioned in the other question are not so much code for the numbers, most of the code there is about other localization issues. For example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135030/ seems rather simple, just replace the Khmer character codes to Myanmar (U+1040 to U+1049 for the numerals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135030/174620) answer recommended by @Marjin is great. I've made a code for Burmese digits. Save this code with the name `burmesedigits.map` and then use command `teckit_compile burmesedigits`. This will give you `.tec` file. Then try the minimal example given below the code.

```
; FC ... 
LHSName "Digits"
RHSName "BurmeseDigits"

pass(Unicode)
U+0030 <> U+1040 ;
U+0031 <> U+1041 ;
U+0032 <> U+1042 ;
U+0033 <> U+1043 ;
U+0034 <> U+1044 ;
U+0035 <> U+1045 ;
U+0036 <> U+1046 ;
U+0037 <> U+1047 ;
U+0038 <> U+1048 ;
U+0039 <> U+1049 ;
```

This is the minimal example -

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=burmesedigits]{Noto Serif Myanmar}

\begin{document}
    123456789
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works great, thank you very much! As an extra aside, thinking for the future, what would your recommendation be if the document needed both Arabic and Myanmar digits? (This ignoring the font issue mentioned in the question).

Comment: You mean the arabic numbering in the page numbers or numbers in general (as in the numbers which you type in the document)?

Comment: Well, it was a busy day yesterday and now that I think about it, if I use a different font that supports both scripts then theoretically I should just be able to type both with the respective keyboards... having Burmese for the page numbers and Arabic numbering in the document might prove more challenging, but I can't think of a case where that would truly be necessary. For now maybe let's just call this settled haha. And thank you again for your help! :)