# How automatic numbering would behave if 0 through 9 are replaced with matching unicode characters in other languages?

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, page-numbering

Relating to the following question I asked:

[Does vref of varioref work with page numbers which are not built-in arabic?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646663/does-vref-of-varioref-work-with-page-numbers-which-are-not-built-in-arabic)

I would like to know the consequences I might encounter if I do the following as a stopgap solution:

I will replace 0, 1, 2, ..., 9 with ၀, ၁, ၂, ၃, ..., ၉ as shown below using FontForge. And then I'll just use LaTex Arabic numbering as it is. My intention for doing this is I expect that LaTex and its packages will use some sort of internal calculation base on normal Arabic numbers. If I inject other unicodes characters in place of the original Arabic numbers, those calculation, most likely, will go wrong. For instance, vref does not behave as expected and has the problem I described in the above question. So, I am making changes at the font level.

In this pic,I've edited my unicode font, Padauk, to clarify what I means.

[image]

Comment: Using a modified custom font might not be the smartest way to approach this. Where do you need Myanmar digits? Page numbers? Chapters? Wouldn't it make more sense to have a macro do this? Have you seen [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498689/)? Also, check out the links there.

Comment: Hi @Ingmar, I could use all the numbering in Myanmar digits already using the following: `%%% Auto numbering in Myanmar %%%
%This macro is to produce myanmar numbering by adopting the thai numbering method
\makeatletter  
\def\@mmnum#1{\expandafter\@@mmnum\number#1\@nil}  
\def\@@mmnum#1{%  
  \ifx#1\@nil  
  \else  
  \char\numexpr#1+"1040\relax  % 1040 is zero character for Burmese.
  \expandafter\@@mmnum\fi  
}  
\renewcommand\@arabic{\@mmnum} % to reset number in \arabic to \mmnum`.

Comment: But I encountered the problem mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646663/does-vref-of-varioref-work-with-page-numbers-which-are-not-built-in-arabic).  [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498689/how-to-use-locale-numbering-custom-numbering-for-burmese)  you mentioned above makes me think a new approach for auto numbering in Burmese. Thanks!

Comment: varioref doesn't care how your numbers look like, you could even put emoji in the positions if you want. But I would suggest to use one of the options in your other questions (and lualatex will work fine with your language, the days where xelatex were the better choice are long gone)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks for the suggestion. I am trying the second option in my other question using \usepackage{zref-vario}
\usepackage{zref-abspage}
\zvsetup{pageprop=abspage}

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I tried LuaLaTex as well for Burmese font rendering. If I don't need justification, LuaLaTex does work well. But as soon as I tried to justify paragraph, I got some stacked burmese are not correctly rendered. For instance it can't  render ကမ္ဘာ့ correctly when paragraph are justified.

Comment: then ask a new question about that, with a proper example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, as suggested I've asked the question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651205/how-can-i-get-my-burmese-text-paragraph-justified-properly-with-lualatex) with some examples. The rendering for ကမ္ဘာ့ is not related to LuaLaTex, but related to XeLaTex. If I remove `\XeTeXinterwordspaceshaping=2` option in XeLaTex, the word is not rendered properly.

Comment: @Ingmar, I tried the method in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/651157/how-automatic-numbering-would-behave-if-0-through-9-are-replaced-with-matching-u) for page numbering in Burmese.  I could get the result I need.  That method also works with varioref references as expected without any problem. Thue full code can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/646663/does-vref-of-varioref-work-with-page-numbers-which-are-not-built-in-arabic) in my own answer to the question. Thanks for your info.